# How to create tables in sqlite 3?

Tags: python, sqlite

I just downloaded sqlite3.exe. It opens up as a command prompt. I created a table test & inserted a few entries in it. I used `.backup test` just in case. After I exit the program using `.exit` and reopened it I don't find the table listed under `.tables` nor can I run any query on it.

I need to quickly run an open source python program that makes use of this table & although I have worked with MySQL, I have no clue about sqlite. I need the minimal basics of sqlite. Can someone guide me through this or at least tell me how to permanently store my tables.

I have put this sqlite3.exe in Python folder assuming that python would then be able to read the sqlite files. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sqlite is built in to Python](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).
You should be able to access your table like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/my.db')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT a_column FROM my_table;").fetchone()
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

You can execute your DDL statements from Python as well.
Make sure to `commit` the changes.

```
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (a_column text);")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: How do I create the first database. I don't have any my.db?

Comment: @Gaurav: `conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/my.db')` will create your database if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks. I used `conn = sqlite3.connect('/Data/patent.db')`. Would you know where this file gets created because I need to delete this table I created called `inv`. I used `c.execute("drop table patent.inv")` but I get this: `OperationalError: no such table: patent.inv`

Comment: @Guarav: try `c.execute("DROP TABLE inv;")`

Answer (score 1):

Why did you download some sqlite3.exe at all? Python should ship with sqlite3 already on board. `import sqlite3` is all you need to do as long as you have a recent Python distribution.
To your problem: I would guess that sqlite3 creates a table in memory by default. Using Python, you need to `dbConn = sqlite3.connect("somefile")` to connect to a database. Then you can use `dbCursor = dbConn.cursor()` to connect to this file. The cursor can execute SQL commands by calling its execute(command) method. For example:
`dbConn.execute("create table test (row text, otherrow real)")`
Finally, you need to call `dbConn.commit()` to save everything you changed in the database.
The Python documentation knows everything else:
http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: what is that "somefile"? If I have just installed python and don't have any database what file do I connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Just execute `sqlite3 foo.db`? This will permanently store everything you do afterwards in this file. (No need for `.backup`.)